# Print the contents of an array (code is one line, for use in Immediate window of visual studio)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Can you write a convenient line of code that prints the contents of an array?

I will use this in the Immediate Window of Visual Studio 2008, so really it has to work in that window.  I may have left out some requirements, but that's pretty much what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
myArray.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Honestly though, I don't think that'll work in the immediate window. It is a nice trick to print it all in one line, but I think for the immediate window, all you need is this:

```
? myArray
```

Comment: Can't use lambdas, and can't assume that Linq is being referenced.

Comment: "Error Binding to Target method"

Comment: what about if the array is a class called person, and you want to print the address of each person

Comment: If you really only want the immediate window, then override ToString() in your Person class.

Comment: It almost works. No overload for 'System.Console.WriteLine(int)' matches delegate 'System.Action<short>'. I hit the breakpoint, I can't change the code, because I don't won't restart the app.

Comment: The question mark operator worked for me. Had to do some remote debugging so I couldn't edit the code on the fly and had to inspect the contents of some variables that were in an ESRI IPropertySet and I didn't know the names of the properties. So I used the GetAllProperties() method to grab all the NAMES and VALUES arrays.  I then just did the ? names then ? values to see those arrays printed out in the immediate window.  Thanks!

Comment: That you for the question mark operator.  Amazing how something so succinct gives me all the information that I need for comparison

Comment: This answer is wrong, is not possible to use Console.WriteLine in Immediate Window.

Answer (score 16):

I use:

```
BitConverter.ToString(bytes); //output: 4A-0B-11-13  etc.
```

Poor BitConverter, always forgotten.

Answer (score 13):

where `a` is the array

```
?a
```

Comment: only prints the first 100 values

Answer (score 11):

```
String.Join("; ", myArray);
```

- [String.Join Method (String, String[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (.NET 2.0 and newer)
- [String.Join Method (String, Object[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  (.NET 4.0 and newer)
- [String.Join Method (String, IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (.NET 4.0 and newer)

Comment: If you print a large float array by this method, be careful that the number printed at the end of the line some of the digits may be separated to the next line.

Comment: You will also lose precision of float numbers in the printed result.

Comment: It uses the default ToString of the type, if that is not what you want to print out, you probably need a loop or a linq statement.

Comment: Note the linq statement can be inside the String.Join in .NET 4.0+.  `String.Join("; ", myArray.Select(i => i.ToString(format, culture))`

Answer (score 4):

You can always create a second variable with the content that you want and check for the value of that.

```
var ids = people.Select(s => s.id).ToList();
```

Would return all of the ids that you are trying to see.

Comment: This worked well for me to quickly grab contents from within a few properties and dump them easily in the immediate window.  I even concatenated a few together to make a phrase like some of the other suggestions  

`var debugstuff = stuff.Select(s=>s.SomeCol +" and " +s.OtherCol).ToList()`

Answer (score 3):

For both the Watch and Immediate windows in Visual Studio, the string returned by ToString() for an object will be used.

So you can override ToString() if you want and format the human-readable representation of any of your classes so that they display the information you need in the Watch or Immediate windows during debugging activities.

For example,

```
public class Foo
{
   public String Bar { get; set; }
   private Int32 _intValue;
   public Int32 Value { get { return _intValue; } }
   override public ToString()
   {
      return "Bar: " + Bar + " has Value: " + Value;
   }
}
```

So now if you create an array of Foo objects named fooArray, typing ? fooArray in the Immediate window will list all the Foo objects with the ToString() return value for each in curly braces. Something like this:

```
? fooArray
{Foo[2]}
[0]: {Bar: hi has Value: 1}
[1]: {Bar: there has Value: 2}
```

Comment: many times you will not own the class that you are using / debugging

Comment: Not precisely true.  The string returned by `ToString()` will not be used (at least in the case of Watch but maybe in Immediate) if you have a `DebuggerDisplay` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you can reference a method in the program you are debugging.  I have a utility method (let's say it's in a MyDebug class):

```
    public static string ToReadableString(byte[] data)
    {
        int length = data.Length;
        var sb = new StringBuilder(length);
        for (int index = 0; index < length; ++index)
        {
            char ch = (char)data[index];
            sb.Append(Char.IsControl(ch) ? '.' : ch);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

and (since my array is named data) add a Watch statement:

```
MyDebug.ToReadableString(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with the byte array contained within a MemoryStream - I found this worked to view the contents of the MemoryStream in the Visual Studio 2010 Watch window:

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(((((System.IO.MemoryStream)(s)))._buffer))
```

Comment: +1 for the `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString` trick, I was looking for something like this

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to just use the watch tab.  But simply typing the name of the array in the immediate tab should return the contents in a somewhat useful format.

Comment: only prints the first 100 values

Answer (score 0):

If you want print for example a array `m` of type `float[4][4]` just type:`(float(*)[4][4])m`